# What is with words like 天気 and ご機嫌 having meanings translated with a "good"?

Tags: etymology

I think the reason why they can mean "good weather" and "good mood" is because they are such familiar expressions that people know what they refer to without their other part. The more I "study" Japanese, the more I realize I do not understand English.

Comment: When you are in shape, you are in good shape. If you have a sense of humor, you have a good sense of humor. I don't think "shape" and "humor" had positive meanings in themselves.

Comment: Are there other adjextives/verbs like the aforementioned?

Comment: In English the words "mood" and "state" have the reverse polarity, with both conveying a "bad mood" or "bad state" by themselves. "He's in a mood," or "this place is in a state." Not sure if that's helpful or not.